# Proving that $d$ defines a metric $d: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have to show that $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = max\{|3x_1 + y_1 − 3x_2 − y_2|, |y_1 − y_2|\}$ defines a metric.

My approach:
Let $x=(x_1,y_1)$ and $y = (x_2,y_2)$

$M_1: d(x,y) \geq 0$ is clearly satisfied since $d$ chooses the maximum value between two values defined by an absolute value.

$$d(x,y) = 0 \iff  max\{|3x_1 + y_1 − 3x_2 − y_2|, |y_1 − y_2|\} = 0 \\
\iff |3x_1 + y_1 − 3x_2 − y_2|= 0 \land |y_1 − y_2| = 0 \\
\iff y_1 = y_2 \land x_1 = x_2.$$
$M_2: d(x,y) = |3x_1 + y_1 − 3x_2 − y_2|$ or $d(x,y) = |y_1 − y_2|$ and in both cases we can add a minus inside the absolute value and get that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

Are these correct? 
I am not sure how to go about $M_3$ since I think there are a lot of cases. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $d((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)) \leq d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) + d((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3))$

Note that since the metric is defined as being the max, it is greater than or equal to both options. That is:

$$
\begin{align}
|y_1-y_2|, |3x_1+y_1-3x_2-y_2| \,\leq& \ d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) \\
|y_2-y_3|, |3x_2+y_2-3x_3-y_3| \,\leq& \ d((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)) 
\end{align}
$$

$ \\ $

Case 1: $\ d((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)) = |y_1-y_3| $

$|y_1-y_3| \leq |y_1-y_2| + |y_2 - y_3| \leq d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) +d((x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)) $

Case 2 is the exact same.

Comment: So we just do this $d((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)) =  |3x_1+y_1−3x_3−y_3| \leq |3x_1+y_1−3x_2−y_2| + |3x_2+y_2−3x_3−y_3|$, right?

Comment: @mandella Correct

Answer (score 1):

Introduce new coordinates $(u,v)$ in the $(x,y)$-space $V:={\mathbb R}^2$, related to $x$, $y$ by
$$u:=3x+y,\quad v:=y,\qquad{\rm resp.,}\qquad x={1\over3}(u-v),\quad y=v\ .$$
In terms of the new cordinates the metric in $V$ is just the metric induced by the $\ell_\infty$-norm
$$\|(u,v)\|:=\max\bigl\{|u|,|v|\bigr\}\ .$$